# Are compound statements lvalue (or rvalue) in C?

Tags: c, compound-assignment

When I examined the definition of the `container_of` macro in Linux Kernel,
I saw a compound statement as a macro definition,

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

however the unclear issue in my mind is which statement gets taken into account as rvalue.
Apparently result of the last statement is used as rvalue, but why?

```
(type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );
```

For instance, is the code example below legal in C?

```
int g_count = 0xFF;

#define GLOBAL_COUNT do {g_count;} while(0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int local;
    local = GLOBAL_COUNT;
    local = 0;
    GLOBAL_COUNT = local;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the assignment rule for variables in compound statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`({})` is a GNU extension to C called a *statement expression*:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

In C a compound statement is a statement and a statement cannot be used in an expression.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is a *statement expression*, not a compound statement. *Statement expression* is a GCC extension that does not exist in standard C language.

In GCC *statement expressions* return their results "by value", meaning that their results are rvalues. This actually is in agreement with general "philosophy" of C language: in C virtually any manipulations over lvalue objects make them to quickly lose their lvalue-ness and turn into rvalues. (In this regard C is virtually opposite of C++. C++ attempts to preserve the lvalue-ness as long as possible.)

Comment: is that true? I tried taking the address of a statement expression and it works as expected. Maybe it's an update to gcc